# Eclipse generating war with incorrect maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss-tools

I have a maven project which compiles into a war file. My pom looks like this:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ber.eg</groupId>
    <artifactId>fle</artifactId>
    <name>lemif</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

In order to use the JBoss Tools integrated in Eclipse I have to change the Properties ->  Deployment Assembly and add a new Source: Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies.

When I deploy my war file into jboss through the Jboss Tools the generated war contains servlet-api-2.5.jar and junit-4.8.1.jar which shouldn't be there.

How can I exclude these jars from the war? (Every time I do a republish or a maven update I have to edit the deploy war and delete these jars).

Thx!

Comment: Well actually, in a properly setup Eclipse Maven project the maven dependencies are on the build path by definition. The fact that you have to manually change anything at all indicates a deeper problem that probably has nothing to do with jboss-tools.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the way eclipse generates the war. But I'm lost, I don't know why eclipse is putting servlet-api and junit into de war's lib directory, because the scope of these dependencies are provided and test. If I generate the war via command line with mvn package the package is fine, the war doesn't contain these jars.